# If int array variable return address of first element of int array then why char array variable not return address of first element?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, printf, implicit-conversion

[Here, i attached code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6rWK.png)
how it treat in char array?

If image is not clear, then refere this code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char c[3] = {'s', 'a', 'h'};
    int a[3] = {1, 2, 3};
    printf("%c\n", c);
    printf("%d\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried this code but not getting expected result. Might be possible I am wrong expecting but want to know why it happening.

Comment: Compile with warnings enabled and then pay attention to those warnings. `c` -> `c[0]` etc. Voting to close as simple typo.

Comment: Although this has already been answered, in future you should include the actual result and expected result in your question. It will help.

Comment: What was the expected result? To print all the elements of both the arrays? You need a loop for that. Also, [don't post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Answer (score 0):

In this code snippet

```
char c[3] = {'s', 'a', 'h'};
int a[3] = {1, 2, 3};
printf("%c\n", c);
printf("%d\n", a);
```

the array designators `c` and `a` used in the calls of `printf` are implicitly converted to pointers to their first elements of the types `char *` and `int *`. In fact you have

```
printf("%c\n", &c[0]);
printf("%d\n", &a[0]);
```

From the C Standard (6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators)

> 3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary &
> operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, **an
> expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an
> expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial
> element of the array object and is not an lvalue.** If the array
> object has register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

But the conversion specifiers `c` and `d` expect objects of the type `char` and `int` correspondingly.

You have to write instead

```
printf("%c\n", *c);
printf("%d\n", *a);
```

That is the same as

```
printf("%c\n", c[0]);
printf("%d\n", a[0]);
```

If you want to output addresses of the first elements of the arrays (that is the same values of the addresses of the whole arrays) you need to use conversion specifier `p`. For example

```
printf("%p\n", ( void * )c);
printf("%p\n", ( void * )a);
```

If you want to output addresses as integers you need to include headers `<inttypes.h>` and `<stdint.h>` (the last is already included in the first header) casting pointers either to the type intptr_t or `uintptr_t` and use appropriate macros. Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main( void )
{
    char c[] = { 's', 'a', 'h' };
    int  a[] = { 1, 2, 3 };

    printf( "address of c is %p\n", ( void * )c );
    printf( "address of c as integer is %" PRIuPTR "\n", ( uintptr_t )c );
    printf( "address of a is %p\n", ( void * )a );
    printf( "address of a as integer is %" PRIuPTR "\n", ( uintptr_t )a );
}
```

The program output might look like

```
address of c is 00C4F8FC
address of c as integer is 12908796
address of a is 00C4F8E8
address of a as integer is 12908776
```

Answer (score -2):

The main reason you can't get expected result is the following.

```
printf("%c\n", c);
```

Here c is the address type not string. If you want to print the first value of char array, you should use *c, because c is the address of the first entry of an array, not the value.

But if you want to print address, print type should be %d or something else, not %c.
This is why printf("%d\n", a) works.

So if you want to print values,

```
printf("%d\n", *a);
printf("%c\n", *c);
```

And if you want to print addresses,
printf("%d\n", a);
printf("%d\n", c);

Comment: _"print type should be %d or something else"_, no it should be `%p`.

Comment: "Here c is the address type not string." --> more like: "Here `c` is an array that is converted to an address when passed to the function."